# Google Cloud Shell, folder that can be accessed by all users in a project

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I need a common space(directory) that every member of a project can access the physical files using the cloud shell

What I want to do is to run console app on the cloud using java command and the jar file can be accessed by my team members of the project, the home directory doesn't provide this. So what is the common directory of the project on the cloud

Comment: You could create a GCS bucket in the project, store the file in the bucket, and then simply download the file from the bucket in the instance's startup script.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't direct support for shared file system in Cloud Shell today.